# Is it normal that the size of apk build under Android Stuio is larger than the same apk build under code base

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

With the same source codes, the size of my built apk is 521KB when it was built within Android Studio while the size of the same apk is 359KB when it was built within whole code base. Is that normal? Or should I add any extra description in my build.gradle to make apk size more reasonable?

Comment: Do you build APK in Android Studio in Release mode with Proguard? Proguard removes unused imports and reduce APK size for about 10-15% for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! It did help! After using Proguard my apk's size become 399 KB! But I 'm still a little curious is it possible to make it even smaller that almost equal to 359 KB?

Comment: Please see my answer. I'll edit it to follow your further research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Studio have special instrument for code shrinking - [Proguard](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/help/proguard.html).

You can enable it by adding the following into your `build.gradle`:

```
  android {
   ...

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
            'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
  }
```

So, if you enable Proguard, it will remove unused imports and final APK will be less.

If there is still difference in APK sizes, you can manually view both APKs (they are simple zip files). You can compare them item by item. Simple APK have the following structure:

```
assets\  
lib\  
META-INF\  
res\  
resources.arsc  
classes.dex  
AndroidManifest.xml
```

The main files are `classes.dex` and `resources.arsc`. Classes is your application binary code, resources is the resources table, that helps Android installer to decompile `res` folder.

Comment: Thanks you very much for your help!! I finally make the apk build under Android Studio has almost the same size(359 KB) with the one build under code base. It turns out the "*.bak" file generated if you use editor like UltraEdit occupy the extra size!

Comment: Conclusion: 1. Using "Proguard"  2. Remove files you don't need like "*.bak",.... from the project

Comment: Hi, Artem

I just found that compare to the apk build under code base, the one build within Andorid Studio has extra folder that contains *.aidl files. Is that normal?
Shouldn't these *.aidl files be wrapped in classes.dex?(or resources.arsc?) 
I had tried to use

    packagingOptions {
        exclude '../mytest/src/com/mytest/aidl/*.aidl'
    }

but it doesn't work! I'm not sure which part goes wrong.....

Comment: I think, this is strange. I've checked own APK and there is no .aidl files (but there are in the sources). I don't exactly know how it should be right. Maybe you need to update Android Studio or Android SDK. I'm using the latest stable version - Android Studio 1.5.1 and Android SDK 24.4.1 with Build Tools 23.0.3

Comment: Hi, Artem Thanks a lot for your help! I had already changed my environment to Android Studio 1.5.1 and Android SDK 23(a slight digression, when I set compileSdkVersion 24.4.1 in my build.gradle, occur: build file 'build.gradle': 20: unexpected token: 1 @ line 20, column 28.
       compileSdkVersion 24.4.1
                              ^
1 error!!??) with Build Tools 23.0.3, but the aidl files still there....... It's really bothersome.............

Comment: I've meant Android SDK 24.4.1 in Android SDK Manager (standalone program for updates check), compileSdkVersion should be 23.

Comment: Sorry, my misunderstanding~ Thanks! BTW, I had asked question of the aidl issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36347480/