# Is it normal that the *.aidl files appeared in the folder of the unzipped apk build within Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I used aidl files in my source codes, but compare to the apk build under code base, the one build within Andorid Studio has extra folder that contains .aidl files. Is that normal? Shouldn't these *.aidl files be wrapped in classes.dex?(or resources.arsc?) 
I also had tried to use

```
packagingOptions { 
    exclude './src/com/mytest/test/*.aidl' 
}
```

but it doesn't work!
following is my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mytest.test"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles 'proguard-apk.config'
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        //androidTest.setRoot('../tests')
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'

        exclude './src/com/mytest/test/*.aidl'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Comment: why are you trying to exclude?

Comment: Because compare to the apk build under code base it wouldn't have the specific folders contain *.aidl files. I suppose those aidl files should be wrapped in classes.dex(? or resources.arsc?) . Since all source codes and folder structure are the same, the apk build within Android studio should have the same behavior(no specific aidl folders contained) with the one build under code base...

Comment: I do not understand your end goal. You include them: `aidl.srcDirs = ['src']` on purpose. This does not work: `exclude './src/com/mytest/test/*.aidl'`.

Comment: I add aidl.srcDirs = ['src'] to let apk build pass but I don't want there would be specific folders contains aidl in the unzipped apk. Because the apk build under code base don't have one. I bothered by the the difference between apk build under code base & within Android Studio. I expect them have the same apk size, unzipped folder structure,...... My goal is to them have the same apk size, unzipped folder structure,......

Comment: 1. Do not override the default gradle source sets unless you really need to 2. I am pretty sure the android gradle plugin is working just fine. 3. Why are you unzipping the apk?

Comment: 1. The reason that I want to change the source set path is because I want to let the source could be build both under code base & Android Studio, so I have to 2. I'm also agree that so I 'm worried about which part did I do wrong 3. Because I'm check the difference in size of apk, I'm worry if the apk build well since it has different folder structure other than the one build under code base.....

Answer (score 1):

Thought it seems passed a long time, I still want to post to help you.
I met the same problem, I resolved it!
try to remove 
resources.srcDirs = ['src']
in you build.gradle
this indicate java resource not android resource, the res already indicate android resource